# Should I test for attributes in an ASP MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd

I have a pretty common scenario on my hands that involves two action methods of the same name - one for handling POST  requests and another for handling GET requests:

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Question question)
{
    repository.Add(question);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

As you can see, the action methods are differentiated by means of an attribute. If I remove the `HttpPost` attribute, the runtime will crash with a yellow screen of death.

My question is: Is it sensible to write a unit test that uses reflection to verify that this particular method is decorated with the `HttpPost` attribute? I have an inclination to do so because if someone accidental removes the attribute, the server will crash.

Comment: You won't hurt anything by adding the unit test, but if you think someone may remove an `HttpPost` attribute, you should probably have a talk with them.

Comment: @Jonesy Well I code solo but your comment does resonate with me.

Comment: If you add a test for every possible thing that could go wrong, you'll be spending a lot of time writing tests... If you're fine with that, then by all means...  However, you usually have to decide where the best value of a test is for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post method already has a different signature in C#, so you are at least testing it exists. I think this is at the tester's discretion but not absolutely necessary. `GET` and `POST` requests are intrinsic to the Web.

If you do decide to do it, you can do something like

```
var postMethod = typeof(NameOfController).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<HttpPost>(false) != null && p.Name == "Add");
Assert.IsTrue(postMethod != null);
```

It may not compile verbatim but that is the gist of it. Make sure to add `System.Reflection` for the extension methods to work.